# How to integrate my email accounts in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to integrate my (`G-Mail`, `Yahoo`, `Hotmail`) accounts in my codeigniter project.

So I search and found [POP3](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/2-Retrieving-email-messages-using-PHP-from-Gmail-Hotmail-and-Yahoo-via-POP3.html) and [IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) for my solution. Its working for G-Mail only But its not working for Yahoo and Hotmail.

I search a lot and try my best but all in vain. I download and include pop3 library in my project also from [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

**Note:** I want to add in my codeigniter project but now I am working for testing purpose in simple php file and all code is written in same file (When I want to test yahoo mail or hotmail code I comment other mail codes) on localhost

```
include "php-mail/class.pop3.php";
```

**Here is G-Mail Code**

```
$gmail_pop3 = new POP3;
$gmail_host = $gmail_pop3->hostname = "pop.gmail.com";
$gmail_port = $gmail_pop3->port = 995;
$gmail_tsl = $gmail_pop3->tls = 1;
$gmail_path = "{" . $gmail_host . ":" . $gmail_port ."/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$gmail_user = "testing.php24@gmail.com";
$gmail_password = '__password__';

$gmail_inbox = imap_open($gmail_path, $gmail_user, $gmail_password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$gmail_emails = imap_search($gmail_inbox,'ALL',SE_UID, "UTF-8");

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($gmail_emails);
echo "</pre>";
```

Its working perfectly for me and give me results

But Yahoo and Hotmail Got issues

**Here is for Yahoo code**

```
$yahoo_pop3 = new POP3;
$yahoo_host = $yahoo_pop3->hostname = "pop.mail.yahoo.com";
$yahoo_port = $yahoo_pop3->port = 995;
$yahoo_tsl = $yahoo_pop3->tls = 1;
$yahoo_path = "{" . $yahoo_host . ":" . $yahoo_port ."/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$yahoo_user = "testing_php24@yahoo.com";
$yahoo_password = '__password__';

$yahoo_inbox = imap_open($yahoo_path, $yahoo_user, $yahoo_password) or die('Cannot connect to Yahoo: ' . imap_last_error());

$yahoo_emails = imap_search($yahoo_inbox,'ALL',SE_UID, "UTF-8");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($yahoo_inbox);
echo "</pre>";

imap_expunge($yahoo_inbox);
imap_close($yahoo_inbox);
```

**Yahoo mail error**

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {pop.mail.yahoo.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in E:\xampp\htdocs\php-mail\pop3.php on line 90
Cannot connect to Yahoo: POP3 connection broken in response
Notice: Unknown: POP3 connection broken in response (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
```

**Here is for Hotmail code**

```
$hotmail_pop3 = new POP3;
$hotmail_host = $hotmail_pop3->hostname = "pop3.live.com";
$hotmail_port = $hotmail_pop3->port = 995;
$hotmail_tsl = $hotmail_pop3->tls = 1;
$hotmail_path = "{" . $hotmail_host . ":" . $hotmail_port ."/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$hotmail_user = "testing_php24@hotmail.com";
$hotmail_password = '__password__';

$hotmail_inbox = imap_open($hotmail_path, $hotmail_user, $hotmail_password) or die('Cannot connect to hotmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$hotmail_emails = imap_search($hotmail_inbox,'ALL',SE_UID, "UTF-8");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hotmail_inbox);
echo "</pre>";

imap_expunge($hotmail_inbox);
imap_close($hotmail_inbox);
```

**Hotmail error**

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in E:\xampp\htdocs\php-mail\pop3.php on line 114
Cannot connect to hotmail: Too many login failures
Notice: Unknown: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

I got very confused what to do. I search a lot but nothing any helpful thing. So please guide me complete and give me working solution for codeigniter

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Yes ... that's i want to said :)

Comment: @KirkBeard Please can you guide me with code reference

Comment: and what about yahoo mail

Comment: You need to change your passwords _immediately_ if you're still using the same one. You've included the passwords in your post. We're currently in the process of redacting them, but this is completely pointless. Your post has already been scraped by who knows how many scraper sites out of our control, and has been included [in several data dumps](https://stackoverflow.blog/cc-wiki-dump/), meaning a redaction just adds a detour for anyone interested in abusing it.